# Adding another time-series in the same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I have the code that is shown below and I want to add another time-series in the data with different color and I am not able to it. Can anyone help ? My time-series data are presented below. The main thing I am trying to do is compare those two timeseries in the same plot in order to acquire further data about the profile of the production.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, date, time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable, get_cmap
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from pandas.core.groupby import SeriesGroupBy


def load_data(
    filename: str = 'WTPV_Spring_2016.csv',
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Load the indicated CSV, parsing dates.
    """

    return pd.read_csv(
        filepath_or_buffer=filename,
        names=('Date', 'Energy'), parse_dates=[0],
        encoding='utf8', delimiter=';',
    )


def make_quantiles(
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    quantiles: np.ndarray,
) -> pd.Series:
    """
    Apply the given quantiles over time groups. The input quantiles are assumed
    to include 0 and 1 but these are not included in the calculation.
    The output is a series with a multi-level index: time, quantile. For plot
    compatibility the time is represented as a time of day on Jan 1 1970.
    """
    fake_date = date(1970, 1, 1)
    def dt_to_time(t: time) -> datetime:
        return datetime.combine(fake_date, t)

    times = df.Date.dt.time.apply(dt_to_time)
    df.set_index(times, inplace=True)
    by_time: SeriesGroupBy = df.Energy.groupby(level=0)
    bands = by_time.quantile(quantiles[1:-1])
    bands.index.names = ('Time', 'Quantile')
    return bands


def plot(quantiles: np.ndarray, bands: pd.Series) -> plt.Figure:
    """
    Plot the given quantile bands as filled regions with an associated colour
    bar. The colour bar shows only the first half of the quantile range; the
    second half is symmetric and implied.
    """
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_title('WT & PV Spring 2016')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax.set_ylabel('Energy (MWh)')

    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

    map = ScalarMappable(
        cmap=get_cmap('viridis'),
        norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=0.5),
    )
    ax.set_facecolor(map.to_rgba(0))
    fig.colorbar(map, label='quantile')

    counterposed_quantiles = np.vstack((
        quantiles[1: len(quantiles)//2],
        quantiles[-2: len(quantiles)//2: -1],
    )).T
    for q0, q1 in counterposed_quantiles:
        y0 = bands.loc[:, q0]
        x = y0.index
        y1 = bands.loc[x, q1]
        ax.fill_between(x, y0, y1, color=map.to_rgba(q0))

    q = 0.5
    y = bands.loc[:, q]
    x = y.index
    ax.plot(x, y, color=map.to_rgba(q))

    return fig


def main() -> None:
    quantiles = np.linspace(0, 1, 41)
    data = load_data()
    bands = make_quantiles(data, quantiles)
    plot(quantiles, bands)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The timeseries

```
2016/09/01 00:00:00;460;0
2016/09/01 01:00:00;376;0
2016/09/01 02:00:00;320;0
2016/09/01 03:00:00;250;0
2016/09/01 04:00:00;207;0
2016/09/01 05:00:00;204;0
2016/09/01 06:00:00;176;0
2016/09/01 07:00:00;134;0
2016/09/01 08:00:00;89;103
2016/09/01 09:00:00;50;420
2016/09/01 10:00:00;43;837
2016/09/01 11:00:00;48;1213
2016/09/01 12:00:00;49;1470
2016/09/01 13:00:00;62;1594
2016/09/01 14:00:00;82;1609
2016/09/01 15:00:00;79;1506
2016/09/01 16:00:00;78;1288
2016/09/01 17:00:00;93;994
2016/09/01 18:00:00;147;645
2016/09/01 19:00:00;191;309
2016/09/01 20:00:00;202;72
2016/09/01 21:00:00;171;0
2016/09/01 22:00:00;163;0
2016/09/01 23:00:00;168;0
2016/09/02 00:00:00;209;0
2016/09/02 01:00:00;244;0
2016/09/02 02:00:00;237;0
2016/09/02 03:00:00;186;0
2016/09/02 04:00:00;142;0
2016/09/02 05:00:00;105;0
2016/09/02 06:00:00;62;0
2016/09/02 07:00:00;55;0
2016/09/02 08:00:00;66;94
2016/09/02 09:00:00;62;376
2016/09/02 10:00:00;49;745
2016/09/02 11:00:00;31;1085
2016/09/02 12:00:00;35;1341
2016/09/02 13:00:00;38;1496
2016/09/02 14:00:00;53;1527
2016/09/02 15:00:00;59;1457
2016/09/02 16:00:00;67;1286
2016/09/02 17:00:00;59;1005
2016/09/02 18:00:00;65;659
2016/09/02 19:00:00;84;326
2016/09/02 20:00:00;135;76
2016/09/02 21:00:00;170;0
2016/09/02 22:00:00;233;0
2016/09/02 23:00:00;281;0
2016/09/03 00:00:00;325;0
2016/09/03 01:00:00;380;0
2016/09/03 02:00:00;395;0
2016/09/03 03:00:00;395;0
2016/09/03 04:00:00;398;0
2016/09/03 05:00:00;433;0
2016/09/03 06:00:00;488;0
2016/09/03 07:00:00;532;0
2016/09/03 08:00:00;603;100
2016/09/03 09:00:00;725;418
2016/09/03 10:00:00;806;840
2016/09/03 11:00:00;886;1220
2016/09/03 12:00:00;938;1483
2016/09/03 13:00:00;966;1622
2016/09/03 14:00:00;941;1648
2016/09/03 15:00:00;956;1568
2016/09/03 16:00:00;919;1374
2016/09/03 17:00:00;881;1086
2016/09/03 18:00:00;858;726
2016/09/03 19:00:00;859;355
2016/09/03 20:00:00;822;78
2016/09/03 21:00:00;809;0
2016/09/03 22:00:00;822;0
2016/09/03 23:00:00;801;0
2016/09/04 00:00:00;733;0
2016/09/04 01:00:00;656;0
2016/09/04 02:00:00;593;0
2016/09/04 03:00:00;570;0
2016/09/04 04:00:00;560;0
2016/09/04 05:00:00;499;0
2016/09/04 06:00:00;417;0
2016/09/04 07:00:00;345;0
2016/09/04 08:00:00;321;100
2016/09/04 09:00:00;335;430
2016/09/04 10:00:00;365;861
2016/09/04 11:00:00;400;1253
2016/09/04 12:00:00;411;1526
2016/09/04 13:00:00;524;1664
2016/09/04 14:00:00;576;1688
2016/09/04 15:00:00;603;1610
2016/09/04 16:00:00;650;1425
2016/09/04 17:00:00;731;1138
2016/09/04 18:00:00;784;762
2016/09/04 19:00:00;885;371
2016/09/04 20:00:00;937;79
2016/09/04 21:00:00;984;0
2016/09/04 22:00:00;984;0
2016/09/04 23:00:00;1001;0
2016/09/05 00:00:00;984;0
2016/09/05 01:00:00;949;0
2016/09/05 02:00:00;928;0
2016/09/05 03:00:00;831;0
2016/09/05 04:00:00;869;0
2016/09/05 05:00:00;827;0
2016/09/05 06:00:00;806;0
2016/09/05 07:00:00;821;0
2016/09/05 08:00:00;793;98
2016/09/05 09:00:00;752;430
2016/09/05 10:00:00;764;865
2016/09/05 11:00:00;754;1263
2016/09/05 12:00:00;772;1539
2016/09/05 13:00:00;759;1673
2016/09/05 14:00:00;669;1697
2016/09/05 15:00:00;609;1603
2016/09/05 16:00:00;568;1384
2016/09/05 17:00:00;549;1078
2016/09/05 18:00:00;559;696
2016/09/05 19:00:00;628;320
2016/09/05 20:00:00;665;63
2016/09/05 21:00:00;677;0
2016/09/05 22:00:00;612;0
2016/09/05 23:00:00;616;0
2016/09/06 00:00:00;652;0
2016/09/06 01:00:00;738;0
2016/09/06 02:00:00;772;0
2016/09/06 03:00:00;794;0
2016/09/06 04:00:00;798;0
2016/09/06 05:00:00;738;0
2016/09/06 06:00:00;757;0
2016/09/06 07:00:00;745;0
2016/09/06 08:00:00;672;64
2016/09/06 09:00:00;668;252
2016/09/06 10:00:00;741;491
2016/09/06 11:00:00;880;718
2016/09/06 12:00:00;992;855
2016/09/06 13:00:00;1022;920
2016/09/06 14:00:00;1114;937
2016/09/06 15:00:00;1177;831
2016/09/06 16:00:00;1193;650
2016/09/06 17:00:00;1237;478
2016/09/06 18:00:00;1218;288
2016/09/06 19:00:00;1171;128
2016/09/06 20:00:00;1216;26
2016/09/06 21:00:00;1243;0
2016/09/06 22:00:00;1201;0
2016/09/06 23:00:00;1106;0
2016/09/07 00:00:00;1119;0
2016/09/07 01:00:00;1129;0
2016/09/07 02:00:00;1075;0
2016/09/07 03:00:00;1030;0
2016/09/07 04:00:00;967;0
2016/09/07 05:00:00;834;0
2016/09/07 06:00:00;794;0
2016/09/07 07:00:00;665;0
2016/09/07 08:00:00;714;43
2016/09/07 09:00:00;811;172
2016/09/07 10:00:00;886;353
2016/09/07 11:00:00;910;537
2016/09/07 12:00:00;874;708
2016/09/07 13:00:00;891;913
2016/09/07 14:00:00;855;1011
2016/09/07 15:00:00;831;1002
2016/09/07 16:00:00;851;969
2016/09/07 17:00:00;907;797
2016/09/07 18:00:00;898;508
2016/09/07 19:00:00;857;238
2016/09/07 20:00:00;839;47
2016/09/07 21:00:00;808;0
2016/09/07 22:00:00;755;0
2016/09/07 23:00:00;756;0
2016/09/08 00:00:00;716;0
2016/09/08 01:00:00;632;0
2016/09/08 02:00:00;562;0
2016/09/08 03:00:00;517;0
2016/09/08 04:00:00;519;0
2016/09/08 05:00:00;484;0
2016/09/08 06:00:00;461;0
2016/09/08 07:00:00;387;0
2016/09/08 08:00:00;278;60
2016/09/08 09:00:00;242;247
2016/09/08 10:00:00;248;477
2016/09/08 11:00:00;258;692
2016/09/08 12:00:00;189;870
2016/09/08 13:00:00;176;1040
2016/09/08 14:00:00;172;1105
2016/09/08 15:00:00;155;1033
2016/09/08 16:00:00;179;905
2016/09/08 17:00:00;188;701
2016/09/08 18:00:00;197;444
2016/09/08 19:00:00;201;215
2016/09/08 20:00:00;223;42
2016/09/08 21:00:00;228;0
2016/09/08 22:00:00;261;0
2016/09/08 23:00:00;249;0
2016/09/09 00:00:00;262;0
2016/09/09 01:00:00;252;0
2016/09/09 02:00:00;241;0
2016/09/09 03:00:00;229;0
2016/09/09 04:00:00;186;0
2016/09/09 05:00:00;204;0
2016/09/09 06:00:00;216;0
2016/09/09 07:00:00;240;0
2016/09/09 08:00:00;260;60
2016/09/09 09:00:00;347;276
2016/09/09 10:00:00;378;555
2016/09/09 11:00:00;431;809
2016/09/09 12:00:00;476;995
2016/09/09 13:00:00;501;1124
2016/09/09 14:00:00;491;1160
2016/09/09 15:00:00;517;1103
2016/09/09 16:00:00;514;979
2016/09/09 17:00:00;527;769
2016/09/09 18:00:00;527;487
2016/09/09 19:00:00;577;220
2016/09/09 20:00:00;666;39
2016/09/09 21:00:00;704;0
2016/09/09 22:00:00;694;0
2016/09/09 23:00:00;656;0
2016/09/10 00:00:00;596;0
2016/09/10 01:00:00;587;0
2016/09/10 02:00:00;574;0
2016/09/10 03:00:00;524;0
2016/09/10 04:00:00;481;0
2016/09/10 05:00:00;469;0
2016/09/10 06:00:00;541;0
2016/09/10 07:00:00;3;0
2016/09/10 08:00:00;14;65
2016/09/10 09:00:00;27;310
2016/09/10 10:00:00;27;629
2016/09/10 11:00:00;77;925
2016/09/10 12:00:00;66;1152
2016/09/10 13:00:00;4;1310
2016/09/10 14:00:00;94;1349
2016/09/10 15:00:00;514;1265
2016/09/10 16:00:00;527;1096
2016/09/10 17:00:00;7;845
2016/09/10 18:00:00;7;531
2016/09/10 19:00:00;66;240
2016/09/10 20:00:00;4;41
2016/09/10 21:00:00;694;0
2016/09/10 22:00:00;242;0
2016/09/10 23:00:00;248;0
2016/09/11 00:00:00;258;0
2016/09/11 01:00:00;189;0
2016/09/11 02:00:00;176;0
2016/09/11 03:00:00;172;0
2016/09/11 04:00:00;155;0
2016/09/11 05:00:00;179;0
2016/09/11 06:00:00;188;0
2016/09/11 07:00:00;197;0
2016/09/11 08:00:00;201;73
2016/09/11 09:00:00;223;359
2016/09/11 10:00:00;28;726
2016/09/11 11:00:00;261;1066
2016/09/11 12:00:00;242;1305
2016/09/11 13:00:00;48;1443
2016/09/11 14:00:00;258;1472
2016/09/11 15:00:00;189;1386
2016/09/11 16:00:00;176;1197
2016/09/11 17:00:00;172;914
2016/09/11 18:00:00;155;569
2016/09/11 19:00:00;179;254
2016/09/11 20:00:00;188;41
2016/09/11 21:00:00;197;0
2016/09/11 22:00:00;201;0
2016/09/11 23:00:00;223;0
2016/09/12 00:00:00;228;0
2016/09/12 01:00:00;261;0
```

The result I am aiming into is those two charts be together in one with each one having different color map.
[image]

[image]

Thank you very much for advance for the help.

Comment: In the above you have mentioned a set of data which I am assuming is time series 1 data so what about time series 2 data ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant,  using the first data after the date and the data after the second semicolon. In order to compare them

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I'm assuming here, that you got the data as part of your code.

```
import pandas as pd

# load csv
df2 = pd.read_csv("two.csv", delimiter=';')

# plot all columns
ax = df2.plot.line()
ax.figure.savefig('test.png')
```

**Output:**

[image: Generated output]

Comment: This is the kind of figure I want, but I want it to be like the results above. Showed like "fanplots"

Comment: Thanks for updating your question, it's clearer now, what you want to achieve.  I'll look into this later.